# Angular ng-if like directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a directive that checks the `tag name` of component and based on some condition shows/hides the component. I want showing hiding to behave like `ng-if` (not initialising controller of component). Example:

```
<my-component custom-if></my-component>
```

Inside the directive `custom-if`:

```
return {
  compile: function($element) {
    if($element[0].tagName === 'some condition'){
      //Element is my-component
      $element.remove();
    }
  }
};
```

The problem I have is that even if I remove element **it still calls controller** of the my-component. Same happens if I remove element inside `compile` or `preLink` function of directive. I also tried to inherit `ng-if` but I can't get the tag name of component inside `custom-if` directive because the element is a `comment` (probably it is `ng-if` specific behaviour to wrap element inside comment)

**UPDATE**: Changed `postLink` function to `compile` to make sure it doesn't work as well. It shows / hides the element but it **always instantiates controller** even if it is removed and that's what I want to avoid

Comment: Instead of doing you logic in link move it to compile. Doing it there should allow you to remove that element from DOM and also exclude that element from linking.

Comment: it doesn't help. I wrote it inside question

Comment: Ok but the key is to tell $compiler to skip link phase of template compilation in compile function. And compiler always returns link function that will always have access to controller (as fourth argument) so unless you'll stop on compile you'll always get a controller. Good question btw.

Comment: have you tried changing the priority to 1001? (see the priority part) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @ChrisHermut so how can I stop the compilation of 'my-component' from 'custom-if' directive?

Comment: It works ( doesn't call the controller) if I inherit ng-if but then the problem is accessing tagName of the element (it says its a comment)

Comment: that's probably because ng-if leaves a comment in place of the removed element as a placeholder

Comment: Whouldn't it be usefull to just check te angular source of ng-if: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/07849779ba365f371a8caa3b58e23f677cfdc5ad/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it by making `customIf` hight priority directive. Then in compile function,  you can check if host component/directive is allowed to continue or not. If not, `customIf` just removes element altogether. If check passes, then `customIf` needs to remove itself by unsetting own attribute and then recompile element again.

Something like this:

```
.directive('customIf', function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1000000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {

      if (element[0].tagName === 'MY-COMPONENT') {
        element.remove();
      }
      else {
        // remove customIf directive and recompile
        attrs.$set('customIf', null);
        return function(scope, element) {
          $compile(element)(scope);
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Y64i7K4vKCF1z3md6LES?p=preview

Comment: In fact, `priority: 1` would suffice. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AnlxqenYQOXjOiFdWOvi?p=preview)

Comment: @Daniel Then it will not work if `myComponent` has high priority. There are some directives that have priority higher than 1. But we still want customIf to execute the first for all of them.

Comment: Can I access the value of `custom-if="$ctrl.smth"` from the compile? For example if I want to check inside compile function `if($ctrl.smth[$element[0].tagName])`

Comment: You can only access scope object in link function. Then it could look something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oajo5G76hNXawupShnEZ?p=preview